# Why doesn't -m switch work when running python script in crontab env?

Tags: python, cron

I can't figure this out. I have a crontab set up like this:

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/env/python -m module.submodule.script
```

Doing this from the command line works fine. The sys.path from the crontab environment includes a path to where module resides.

When the crontab executes, I get a "No module named module.submodule.script" error. Not a traceback, mind, it's the python command that throws that error.

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/env/python -m module
```

Also results in a "No module named module" error.

I don't want to know how to run the script from crontab, I already have done that fine, I just want to understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Try this 0 0 * * * /path/to/python test.py >> test.out In test.py add `import sys;import pprint;pprint.pprint(sys.path)` With this it is possible to find out module is available in sys.path.

Comment: I tried that and the module is in its path. But when I use the -m switch, it doesn't find the module. I don't even get a traceback, it's as if it hasn't run yet at all.

Comment: `>>` should store exceptions too. Hope you specified python module in quotes, like `python -m "fabric.main".

Comment: I'll ask the python gurus on the mailing lists.